# Arduino Ethernet Client not working using IP address only

Tags: url, arduino, ethernet

I am trying to communicate with my hosted server using an Arduino Ethernet [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields).

Now the problem is this:

Using a web browser, I can see that calling the URL works fine, but calling the IP address does not. I assume that the hosting provider hosts several different URLs using the same IP address.

How can I make a URL dependent call from within the Arduino libraries? The standard Arduino libraries only require the IP address of my host, not the URL.

Comment: you're probably hosted via http/1.1 named-based vhost, which REQUIRE a valid `Host:` header in the http request. poking at the bare IP address doesn't work, because the webserver won't know WHICH of the many sites on that IP you're trying to access.

Comment: Could you post some code to show us what you're working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure the http GET/POST request has the correct `Host` field.
Here's a sample get request from http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

There's a lot of good technical information on this site.

### Sample HTTP Get Request:

```
 GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.w3.org
```

This may require some customization of your code, but should do the trick !!

Answer (score 0):

other options:

- https://github.com/interactive-matter/HTTPClient or
- https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient